# React Native Paper Dark Theme

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-paper

How do I set the theme to dark theme in React Native Paper? In all my screens, all the `<View>`'s still have white backgrounds.

```
const theme = {
      ...DarkTheme,
      colors: {
        ...DarkTheme.colors,
        primary: '#2d3436',
        accent: '#1C1C1C',
        background : '#636e72'
      }
    };

render() {
   return(
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
         <App />
      </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying a theme and provider level wont change all the views.
You will have to use the 'withTheme' when exporting which would provide the theme prop which you can use to access the colors.

```
import { withTheme } from 'react-native-paper';
const Test = ({ theme,children }) => {
  const { colors } = theme;
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
     {children}
    </View>
  );
};

export default withTheme(Test);
```

If you want to use the same theme for all Views, create a custom wrapper component which sets the color like above

Comment: Is there a way to access the theme from a stylesheet file? I typically have separate stylesheet files for my components and it would be very useful to be able to access colors I set in the theme directly in my stylesheets.

Comment: As I know, the themes are passed via context so you need to access via the component

Comment: Looks like I can do this: `<View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: colors.background }]}>`. I access the colors by doing this: `const { colors } = theme`;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding extra hooks on every screen/component you can configure the theme with react-navigation.

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/theming-with-react-navigation#passing-theme-with-providers

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the theme at `<NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>{your code}</NavigationContainer>`.

The `navigationTheme` is of the type `Theme`, but react native paper theme is of the type `MD3Theme`, so you will have to addapt your `MD3Theme` to the type `Theme`.

I have made it like this

```
const navigationTheme = {
        dark: colorScheme === "dark",
        colors: {
          border: theme.colors.background,
          background: theme.colors.background,
          card: null,
          notification: theme.colors.outline,
          primary: theme.colors.primary,
          text: theme.colors.outline,
        },
      };
```

where `theme` is my preconfigured `MD3Theme`.